# Calculating the area under the curve: $\frac{\mu^x\cdot e^{-\mu}}{Γ(x+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, area

I am trying to calculate the area under the curve for the function:

Formula 1: $$\frac{\mu^xe^{-\mu}}{Γ(x+1)}$$

Where:

1. $x = 0$ and $x = 1$
2. $μ = 0.5$

The Indefinite Integral equation WolframAlpha gives me is:

Formula 2:

$$\int \frac{μ^xe^{-μ}}{Γ(x+1)}\,dx = \frac{e^{-μ} \operatorname{Ei}((x+1)\ln(μ))}{Γ(μ)}$$

(see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%CE%BC%5Ex%29*%28e%5E-%CE%BC%29%29%2F%28%CE%93*%28x%2B1%29%29) link )

When I solve this equation for $x = 1$ and $x = 0$, and subtract the latter from the former, I end up with $0.088975$ area units.

Having an area value so small between $x = 0$, and $x = 1$ makes no sense to me.

Just by looking at the curve in excel, I can see that when $x = 0$, $y = 0.606$. And when $x = 1$, $y = 0.303$. The area should be approximately $75\%$ of a rectangle with dimensions $0.606 \cdot 1 = 0.606$ area units.

Any help/insight would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you misread $\Gamma(x+1)$ as $\Gamma \cdot (x+1)$ where $\Gamma$ is some constant. Here, $\Gamma()$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). You have to use `Gamma[]` in WolframAlpha. Anyway, when $x$ is an integer, the usual way to compute this is integration by parts and with the knowledge that $\Gamma(x) = (x-1)!$.

Comment: You were right, turns out that there is no Indefinite Integral generated by WolframAlpha for Formula 1.

Unfortunately, I started out with the Poisson Distribution formula and intentionally replaced the factorial denominator, x! with the Gamma function so that I could solve the equation for instances where x >= 0 and continuous. 

What would be your recommendation for calculating the area under the curve for Formula 1 where x >= 0?

Comment: There is really nothing to compute here, since $\int_0^\infty \mu^x e^{-\mu} \, d\mu$ is the *definition* of $\Gamma(x+1)$. So the integral (with the normalizing factor $1/\Gamma(x+1)$ )is just $1$. (Also, saying $\mu=0.5$ makes no sense if your integral is with respect to $\mu$.)

Comment: The Wolfram alpha web site integrated with respect to $x$.  But I suspect you want to integrate with respect to $\mu$.  Then it is called the incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems I have a disconnect.

I have plotted Formula 1 in excel with increments of of x increasing by 0.1 from 0 to 4. I have a fixed μ = 0.5 value. Perhaps I should label this something else? I'm really just using μ as a fixed numerical constant I adjust to get the desired graph shape (increasing shifts y_max right and simultaneously reduces amplitude).

All I want to know is if it's possible to calculate the area under my graph between 0 and any given decimal value of x, say x = 0.7, given a fixed value of 'μ'. And if this is possible, how...

Many thanks in advance, J

Comment: See [mu function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MuFunction.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am quite skeptical about a possible closed form of the antiderivative
$$I=e^{-μ}\int \frac{μ^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}\,dx$$

However, assuming that we should always stay in the range $0 \leq x \leq 1$, we could make some approximations representing $\Gamma(x+1)$ as a more or less constrained polynomial in $x$

$$\Gamma(x+1) \sim \sum_{n=0}^p a_n x^n=a_p \prod_{n=1}^p (x-r_n)$$ Then partial fraction decomposition would lead to
$$I=\frac {e^{-μ}}{a_p} \sum_{n=1}^p b_n\int \frac{\mu^x}{x-r_n}\,dx$$
$$J_n=\int \frac{\mu^x}{x-r_n}\,dx=\mu ^{r_n}\, \log (\mu)\,\text{Ei}\big[x-r_n\big]  $$

Trying for $\mu=0.5$ and a few values of $p$ for the integral between $0$ and $1$, the following results were obtained (no constraint for the curve fit)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \text{approximation} \\
 2 & 0.47485397 \\
 3 & 0.47487261 \\
 4 & 0.47487351 \\
 5 & 0.47487387 \\
 6 & 0.47487409
\end{array}
\right)$$
while the exact value is $0.47487382$.

**Edit**

Another possibility is to use
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{c_n}{n!}\,x^n +O(x^{p+1})$$ where the very first coefficients are (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B1%2FGamma%5B1%2Bx%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C10%7D%5D))
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & \gamma  \\
 2 & \gamma ^2-\frac{\pi ^2}{6} \\
 3 & \gamma ^3-\frac{\gamma  \pi ^2}{2}+2 \zeta (3) \\
 4 & \gamma ^4-\gamma ^2 \pi ^2+\frac{\pi ^4}{60}+8 \gamma  \zeta (3) \\
 5 & \gamma ^5-\frac{5 \gamma ^3 \pi ^2}{3}+\frac{\gamma  \pi ^4}{12}-\frac{10}{3}
   \left(-6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) \zeta (3)+24 \zeta (5) \\
 6 & \gamma ^6-\frac{5 \gamma ^4 \pi ^2}{2}+\frac{\gamma ^2 \pi ^4}{4}-\frac{5 \pi
   ^6}{168}-20 \gamma  \left(-2 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) \zeta (3)+40 \zeta
   (3)^2+144 \gamma  \zeta (5)
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$K_n=\int \mu^x \,x^n \,dx=-x^{n+1} E_{-n}\big[-x \log (\mu )\big]$$

Using the terms given in the link, the results is $0.47487437$.

**Update**

Another possibility is based on the fact that$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}-1$$ looks like a Gibbs enxcess energy model.

So, let use write
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}=1+x(x-1) \sum_{k=0}^p d_k\, x^k$$ This would make

$$I=e^{-μ}\Big[\frac{\mu ^x}{L} +\sum_{k=0}^p (-1)^k d_k L^{-k}\,\left(\frac{\Gamma (k+3,-x L)}{L^3}+\frac{\Gamma (k+2,-xL
   ))}{L^2} \right)\Big]$$ where $L=\log(\mu)$.

For $p=3$, we should have
$$d_0=-\gamma\qquad d_1=-\gamma -\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{12}$$
$$d_2==48+16 \gamma +2 \gamma ^2-\frac{\pi ^2}{3}+\frac{16 (-8+\gamma +2\log
   (2))}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$
$$d_3=\frac{384-6 (32+\gamma  (10+\gamma )) \sqrt{\pi }+\pi ^{5/2}+96 (2-\gamma -2\log
   (2))}{3 \sqrt{\pi }}$$ which reproduce the function and first derivative values at $x=0$, $x=\frac 12$ and $x=1$.

For the test example, the result would be $0.47487809$