# Approximation of $\Big[\Gamma(1+x)\Big]^{-1}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ (for the art for art's sake).

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation, gamma-function

Recently was asked on the site the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3803413/calculating-the-area-under-the-curve-frac-mux-cdot-e-mu%ce%93x1) : how to compute
$$f(t)=\int_0^t\frac{\mu^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}\ dx$$ for which I assumed $0 \leq t \leq 1$. There is no antiderivative available from any CAS I tried.

My first idea was to approximate $\Gamma(x+1)$ by a more or less constrained polynomial in $x$, then to use partial fraction decomposition. This leads to a linear combination of elliptic integrals.

Later, I found that  $\Big[\Gamma(1+x)\Big]^{-1}$ looks to be very similar to a Gibbs excess energy diagram for a binary system. Some models of this physical properties are very simple (Van Laar, Margules), but they only have two parameters which is not enough for an "accurate" representation of the function. Much more accurate are  Scatchard-Hildebrand, Wilson, NRTL or Uniquac models but  their complexity would not allow the required integration.

So, with a limited choice, I decided to try with a model looking like the one proposed by Redlich-Kister which contains a pure polynomial component. So my idea was to write
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}\sim 1+x(x-1) \sum_{k=0}^p d_k\, x^k$$
$$f(t)=\frac{\mu ^t-1}{L}+$$ $$\sum_{k=0}^p (-1)^k\,d_k  L^{-(k+3)} (L\, \Gamma (k+2,-L t)+\Gamma (k+3,-L t)-(k+L+2) \Gamma (k+2))$$ where $L=\log(\mu)$ (provided that $\Re(\log (\mu ))<0\land \Re(k)>-2$).

Willing to stay non-empirical, in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3803413/calculating-the-area-under-the-curve-frac-mux-cdot-e-mu%ce%93x1), I used $p=3$ and the $d_k$'s were computed in order to  match the function and first derivative values at $x=0$, $x=\frac 12$ and $x=1$. The result were no too bad.

For *the art for art's sake*, I decided to use $p=6$, the $d_k$'s were computed in order to  match the function, first and second derivative values at $x=0$, $x=\frac 12$ and $x=1$. This leads to
$$d_0=-\gamma \qquad d_1=-\gamma -\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{12}$$

$$4 \sqrt \pi\,d_2=6 (178+3 \gamma  (8+\gamma )) \sqrt{\pi }+32 \pi ^2-3 \pi ^{5/2}-64 \left(P^2+4 P+36\right)$$
$$3 \sqrt \pi\,d_3=-3 (1356+\gamma  (111+16 \gamma )) \sqrt{\pi }-144 \pi ^2+8 \pi ^{5/2}+96
   \left(3 P^2+8 P+92\right)$$
$$3 \sqrt \pi\,d_4=2 \left(3 (1376+\gamma  (61+14 \gamma )) \sqrt{\pi }+156 \pi ^2-7 \pi ^{5/2}-24
   \left(13 P^2+20 P+372\right)\right)$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}\,d_5=-\left(628+9 \gamma +6 \gamma ^2\right) \sqrt{\pi }-24 \pi ^2+\pi ^{5/2}+16
   \left(3 P^2+2 P+84\right)$$
$$3 \sqrt \pi\,d_6=-4 \left(-6 (106+(\gamma -1) \gamma ) \sqrt{\pi }-24 \pi ^2+\pi ^{5/2}+48
   \left(P^2+28\right)\right)$$ where
$P=\psi \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=2-\gamma -2\log (2)$

The maximum absolute error is $1.5 \times 10^{-8}$ which seems to be decent.

Making the numbers rational, this would give
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}\sim 1+x(1-x) P_6(x)$$
$$P_6(x)=\frac{2807}{4863}-\frac{247}{3140}x-\frac{461 }{3820}x^2+\frac{66
   }{1435}x^3+\frac{11 }{3303}x^4-\frac{15 }{2726}x^5+\frac{3
  }{2750}x^6$$

A few values of the definite integral (just for comparison)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mu & t & \text{approximation} & \text{exact}     \\
 0.25 & 0.2 & 0.182857067200 & 0.182857068268 \\
 0.25 & 0.4 & 0.329965795201 & 0.329965797571 \\
 0.25 & 0.6 & 0.443007596935 & 0.443007599310 \\
 0.25 & 0.8 & 0.526656210875 & 0.526656212492 \\
 0.25 & 1.0 & 0.586607844050 & 0.586607845209 \\
      &     &                &                \\ 
 0.50 & 0.2 & 0.195704099746 & 0.195704100926 \\
 0.50 & 0.4 & 0.376453536397 & 0.376453539149 \\
 0.50 & 0.6 & 0.535922898037 & 0.535922900791 \\
 0.50 & 0.8 & 0.671420159082 & 0.671420160584 \\
 0.50 & 1.0 & 0.782934567076 & 0.782934567750 \\
      &     &                &                \\ 
 0.75 & 0.2 & 0.203784473259 & 0.203784474510 \\
 0.75 & 0.4 & 0.407825165336 & 0.407825168343 \\
 0.75 & 0.6 & 0.602995831714 & 0.602995834721 \\
 0.75 & 0.8 & 0.782793915893 & 0.782793917219 \\
 0.75 & 1.0 & 0.943235581611 & 0.943235581767
\end{array}
\right)$$

I am more than happy with these results but,again, just for *the art for art's sake*, I would like to be even better. For sure, I could use $p=9$ and obtain the parameters in order to  match the function, first, second and third derivative values at $x=0$, $x=\frac 12$ and $x=1$; this would lead to monstreous expressions.

> So, my question is : without any curve fit and avoiding so many terms, is there a way to obtain a better (mathematically based) approximation of $\Big[\Gamma(1+x)\Big]^{-1}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$

Comment: See my own question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709724/conjectured-upper-bound-frac-gammaxn-gammax-and-limit-at-infinity

Comment: @njuffa. This is a nice and interesting obervation. I shall look around. Thanks.

Comment: Claude have you considered the function $f(x)=ax\ln(x)+1$ with $0<a<1$ to make an approximation of the $\Gamma(x+1)$ with $0\leq x\leq 1$ ?Good day !

Comment: @c-love-garlic. Good idea but bad result ! This would give $a\sim -0.34$. Any idea or suggestion is welcomed. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici have you considered $f(x)=\Gamma(x^x+1)$ the abscissa of the minimum  is near from $e^{-e^{-1}}$ ?

Comment: @ErikSatie. I do not understand since the minimum of $f(x)=\Gamma(x^x+1)$ occurs at $x=\frac 1e$. Please clarify. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Well  you're right there is a problem of calculations with Geogebra . Anyway if we can make an approximation of $f(x)$ using the minimum  then we can use the Lambert's function to solve  $x^x=y$ and deduce something usefull (?) . It is a good idea ? . Cheers :-).

Comment: @ErikSatie. Interesting idea ! I shall look at it. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Using the idea describe above we have $f(x)=\Gamma(x^x+1)\approx g(x)=e^{x^{4.2}\alpha-e^{-4.2}\alpha}f(e^{-1})$ where $\alpha$ verifying $g(1)=1$ for $e^{-1}\leq x\leq 1$ . It's the best I can do and it's a little bit bad :-( .

Comment: @ErikSatie. I think that I could do the same as for $\Big[\Gamma(1+x)\Big]^{-1}$. I shall try tomorrow morning (almost dinner time here). Taking into account your username and your profile, I think that we share many things beside mathematics. Do you know his house ? I love this place. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ErikSatie. I have built a quite good approxiamtion of $\Gamma(x^x+1)$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac 34$.

Comment: @ClaudeDebussy what tools you have used ? quite as $<10^{-3}$ ? cheers :-)

Comment: @ErikSatie. Around $0.005$ using something like a $[2,2]$ Padé approximant. The parameters are derived from function and derivative values at $x=0$, $x=\frac 1 e$ and $x=1$. Send me an e-mail (my adress is in my profile) and I shall send you all this stuff. May be, you could post a question here to see what comes. Cheers (and thanks for my new last name). :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hi I have good news as in one of my previous question have you considered the function $f(x)=\Gamma(x+1)^{x^x}$ ? (the minimum is near $x=0.5$) .Good day !!!

Comment: @ErikSatie. I think that this one could be quite simple. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's not ironic I suppose.

Comment: @ErikSatie. I am serious. The formulae will be awful because the minimum is not at a known value but the same kind of method would work.

Comment: Hi Claude Are you fine see $\Gamma{(x^{\Gamma{(x^{\Gamma{(x^2)}}})}-x^{\Gamma{(x)}}+x})\geq \Gamma{(x)}$ from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4242661/refinement-about-gammax-gammax-gammax2-x-gammaxx-ge .Un petit rien pour vous !:-)Good night in Pau .

Comment: For the improper case, please try the [mu function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MuFunction.html).

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Could you please elaborate ? By the way, you produce extremely interesting problems that I always follow. My problem is that 99.999999% of the time I am just unable to contribute. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The mu function is defined fairly by “ Erdélyi et al. 1981a, p. 388; Prudnikov et al. 1990, p. 798; Gradshteyn and Ryzhik “, as seen in the link. It is a generalized version of the Mellin transform of the gamma function, so it can solve $$\int_0^\infty\frac{t^n k^t}{(x+a)!}$$ in closed form, in terms of the [**Nu**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NuFunction.html) or Mu function. By the way, the same people also defined the [Lambda function equation **(3)**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambdaFunction.html) generalizing the integral of the factorial. For $t=\infty$, use ν(a,x).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. [+1] You put good effort into your questions, but mine are normal questions. I thought you could use these [rare, _nu, mu, and lambda, special functions_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144970/area-under-inverse-gamma-function-branch-from-minimum-to-1-equivalent-to-1-in) for your problem. Does this help?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici look at : $$g\left(x\right)=\frac{2x}{x^{0.85x}+1}-\frac{\left(x\left(1-x\right)\right)^{2}}{8}-\frac{\left(x\left(1-x\right)\right)^{4}}{2}-6\left(x\left(1-x\right)\right)^{6}-6\left(x\left(1-x\right)\right)^{8}-12\left(x\left(1-x\right)\right)^{10}-\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}n^{e}\left(x\left(1-x\right)\right)^{2\left(n+1\right)},1-\ln\left(\frac{g\left(x\right)}{x}\right)\simeq x!$$ around $x=1$

Comment: @ErikSatie. This is amazing ! Thanks & cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici A last one for the the pleasure : $$f\left(x\right)=1-\ln\left(\frac{2}{\left(x^{0.85x^{1.27}}+1\right)}\right)+\frac{x\left(1-x\right)}{32}-\frac{\left(x^{2}\left(1-x\right)\right)^{2}}{4}-\frac{\left(x\left(1-x^{2}\right)\right)^{4}}{25}-\frac{\left(x^{2}\left(1-x\right)\right)^{6}}{4}-\frac{\left(x\left(1-x^{2}\right)\right)^{8}}{4}-10000\left(x^{2}\left(1-x\right)\right)^{10}-3\left(x\left(1-x^{2}\right)\right)^{12}-650000\left(x^{2}\left(1-x\right)\right)^{14}-0.2\left(x\left(1-x^{2}\right)\right)^{16}\simeq x!$$ Try for $x=0.7128$

Comment: Let : $$f\left(x\right)=\frac{x!}{x^{2}+1}$$ then define : $g\left(x\right)=1+f'\left(0\right)x,a_{1}\left(x\right)=\frac{\left|f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right|}{x+1},a_{2}\left(x\right)=x\left(0.5-x\right)a_{1}\left(0.25\right),a_{3}\left(x\right)=\frac{\left|a_{1}\left(x\right)-a_{2}\left(x\right)\right|}{x+1},a_{4}\left(x\right)=x\left(0.5-x\right)a_{3}\left(0.25\right),\operatorname{and so on...}$ then it seems to converges around $x\in[0,\epsilon]$ where $\epsilon<0.25$.Now multiply by $x+1$, $n$ times and you got something I think ...Give me your feedback !

Comment: See $$\left(f\left(x\right)\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)!\right)^{-1}\right)+\frac{1}{50}\left(15\left(x-0.5689\right)^{2}\left(1-x\right)^{2}+160\left(x-0.5689\right)^{2}\left(1-x\right)^{4}+1000\left(x-0.5689\right)^{4}\left(1-x\right)^{4}\right),f\left(x\right)=x^{-\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2}-\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{4}-\frac{9}{5}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{6}-2\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{8}+\ln\left(x\right)},x!$$ Cheers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{1 \over \Gamma\pars{x + 1}} = {1 \over x!}
=
{x + 1 \over \pars{x + 1}!} =
{\pars{x + 2}\pars{x + 1} \over \pars{x + 2}!}
\\[5mm] = &\ \cdots =
{\prod_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{x + k} \over \pars{x + n}!} \\[5mm] \approx &\
{\prod_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{x + k} \over
\root{2\pi}\pars{x + n}^{x + n + 1/2}\,\,\,\expo{-n - x}} =
{\tt mySol}\pars{x,n}
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: Very interesting approach ! Thanks for it. By the way, when I see some answers, I know they are from you since you have a very personal style. I suppose that you don't remember but we met in Caracas some 30+ years ago. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 4):

My try : we have on $x\in[1,2]$ :

$$1+4(x-1)(x-2)\left(1-\Gamma\left(\left(\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}\right)^{2}\right)\right)\simeq \Gamma(x)$$

It's not really tight but it's simple in the form.

Hope it helps you Claude.

Edit :

Around $x=2$ we have :

$$\Gamma(x)\simeq ((1-x)\frac{1}{2}(\gamma-1)+1+\frac{1}{2}(\gamma-1))^x$$

Edit 2:

Using the inverse function of the Lambert's function and denotes by :

$$g(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}xe^x\right)^{x+1}$$

We have $1\leq x \leq 2$:

$$\Gamma(x)\simeq (g(1-x))^x$$

---

---

We have on $(-1,0)$ the approximation :

$$(\operatorname{W}(-ex))^{(\operatorname{W}(-x))^{1.45}}\simeq (\Gamma(1-x))^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$$

---

---

For $1\leq x\leq 2$ it seems we have the inequality :

### $$f(x)=\left(\Gamma(x)\tanh(x)\right)^{\frac{2}{x(1+\tanh(e^{-1}x))}}$$

$$f(x)\leq \frac{f(1)-f(2)}{-1}(x-1)+f(1)$$

And the difference is less than $1*10^{-3}$

Last edit :

### $$f(x)=\left(\Gamma(x)\tanh(x)\right)^{\frac{2}{x(1+\tanh(0.25x))}}$$

For $1\leq x\leq 2$ it seems we have the inequality :

$$(f(x))''>0$$

So we can get using convexity an arbitrary accuracy following the lenght of the interval .

Comment: Thanks, Erik ! Did you read my answer ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What do you think about my edit ?

Comment: This is interesting ! Thanks, Erik !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Last edit what do you think about ?

Comment: Interesting again ! Thanks, Erik.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici A present for you ^_^ check : $\left(l\left(x\right)\right)^{\left(\frac{\ln\left(2\right)}{\ln\left(l\left(2\right)\right)}\right)}\left(1-\frac{\frac{10}{3}\left(x-1\right)^{2}\left(x-2\right)}{\left(x+1\right)\left(x+2\right)}\right)<x!$ where $l\left(x\right)=\left(g\left(x\right)x^{\frac{1}{x}}+x^{x}\right)$ and $g(x)=1-x^{0.5x}$ for $1<x<2$

Comment: Be sure that I appreciate !  You just proved that $$\lim_{\text{time}\to \infty } \, \text{[Erik Satie's imagination}]=\infty^\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

Letting $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$, the Gamma function may be defined through the following limit for an arbitrary $\alpha$ where $x\approx0$ and $x\approx\alpha^2$ for $\alpha\approx1$ are most accurate:

$$x!=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n+\alpha\right)^x\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac xk\right)^{-1}$$

which has simple inverse given by

$$x!^{-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n+\alpha\right)^{-x}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac xk\right)$$

In the given problem, this leads to an integrand of the form $P(x)\phi^x$ for polynomial $P$ and constant $\phi$, which can be evaluated elementarily.

It's also worth pointing out that refining the estimate by taking larger $n$ does not involve a lot of recalculation since it is just one additional term on the product. However, the convergence is not very fast.

Choosing something such as $\alpha=0.9$ should lead to a good balance of over- and under-estimates of the Gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is curve fitting, but it involves only 3 parameters. The accuracy is better than 0.13% over all $0<x<1$; good, but nothing like Claude's 8 digits or so.  The idea is that the local max is not exactly at 1/2, as implied the factor $x(1-x)$ in Claude's analysis.

$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+x)} \approx 1+ A \ x^b (1-x)^c $$
$$ A=0.538 , \ b=0.971 ,\ c=1.095 $$

The error is close to minimax; that is, the amplitudes of the difference curve are approximately equal.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! But, as I wrote, I do not want any empirical curve fit. Next, how would you compute the integral $f(t)$ ? "My" maximum is not at $x=1/2$; for the rigorous function, the coordinates of the extremum are $(0.461632145,1.12917389)$ and for the approximation $(0.461632154,1.12917389)$. Cheers and thanks again for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

What is below is exactly what I do not want to do. It is just posted to show that high order polynomials are highly significant.

What I did was to generate $10001$ equally spaced data points of
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1) x}\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma (x+1)}-1\right)\qquad \qquad -\gamma \leq f(x) \leq -1+\gamma$$ using high precision.

Then, polynomial regressions; below is an example of the results for a polynomial of degree $9$ (it leads to maximum absolute errors $\sim 10^{-11}$).

$$\begin{array}
 \text{   } & \text{Estimate of } d_k           & \sigma\text{ for }d_k  \\
 1 &   -0.5772156649 & 2.449\times 10^{-13}  \\
 x &   +0.0786624078 & 1.399\times 10^{-11}  \\
 x^2 & +0.1206650090 & 2.600\times 10^{-10}  \\
 x^3 & -0.0458731951 & 2.221\times 10^{-9}   \\
 x^4 & -0.0036781095 & 1.028\times 10^{-8}   \\
 x^5 & +0.0059542170 & 2.790\times 10^{-8}   \\
 x^6 & -0.0012903855 & 4.563\times 10^{-8}   \\
 x^7 & -0.0000841706 & 4.421\times 10^{-8}   \\
 x^8 & +0.0000893923 & 2.336\times 10^{-8}   \\
 x^9 & -0.0000138358 & 5.183\times 10^{-9}  
\end{array}$$

**Edit**

In view of these results, I made the calculations for $p=9$ matching the function, first, second and third derivative values at $x=0$, $x=\frac 12$ and $x=1$; this effectively leads to monstrous expressions (I shall not type them but they are available); as one could expect, the same constants plus $\zeta(3)$ appear in their expressions. The maximum absolute error is $1.1 \times 10^{-11}$.

Now, the same table as before
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mu & t & \text{approximation} & \text{exact}     \\
 0.25 & 0.2 & 0.182857068266992 & 0.182857068267690 \\
 0.25 & 0.4 & 0.329965797569747 & 0.329965797571307 \\
 0.25 & 0.6 & 0.443007599308124 & 0.443007599309699 \\
 0.25 & 0.8 & 0.526656212489610 & 0.526656212491646 \\
 0.25 & 1.0 & 0.586607845206624 & 0.586607845208931 \\
      &     &                &                \\ 
 0.50 & 0.2 & 0.195704100925464 & 0.195704100926239 \\
 0.50 & 0.4 & 0.376453539146954 & 0.376453539148764 \\
 0.50 & 0.6 & 0.535922900789419 & 0.535922900791250 \\
 0.50 & 0.8 & 0.671420160581682 & 0.671420160584277 \\
 0.50 & 1.0 & 0.782934567746625 & 0.782934567749710 \\
      &     &                &                \\ 
 0.75 & 0.2 & 0.203784474509130 & 0.203784474509953 \\
 0.75 & 0.4 & 0.407825168340619 & 0.407825168342596 \\
 0.75 & 0.6 & 0.602995834719402 & 0.602995834721404 \\
 0.75 & 0.8 & 0.782793917216033 & 0.782793917219063 \\
 0.75 & 1.0 & 0.943235581763057 & 0.943235581766778
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: For comparison, coefficients of minimax $P_{9}$ (matches at $x=0$, $x=1$) with maximum absolute error $< 10^{-12}$: `5.7721566490547482e-1, -7.8662407402331200e-2, -1.2066501595952826e-1, 4.5873243335408945e-2, 3.6779360284088752e-3, -5.9538708486641407e-3, 1.2900033631901313e-3, 8.4380677149800901e-5, -8.9427608944409487e-5, 1.3828612244534447e-5`

Comment: @njuffa. Thanks ! This is nice but the problem with *minimax* is that you do not have any idea about the significance of resulting parameters.

Comment: @gary. No idea ? Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Partial second answer.

Inspired by @FelixMarin's answer I found :

Let $2/3<x<1$ and define :

### $$f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{x}e^{\frac{1}{12x+\left(e-2\right)x^{-x}\cdot2^{-x}-\left(e-2\right)x^{x^{x}}+1-C}}$$

Where $C$ is the Catalan's constant .

Then it seems we have :

$$0<\frac{f\left(x\right)}{f\left(1\right)}-x!<8*10^{-5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hi Claude I find the following nice:

Let $x\in(0,1)$ and

$$f(x)=x!^{\frac{1}{x-1}},\quad g(x)=\frac{ f(0)-f(1) }{-1}\left(x-1\right)+f(1)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{x^{2n}\left(1-x\right)^{2n}}{\left(2\pi\right)^{n}}\right).$$

Then $k=10$

$$\left(g(x)\right)^{x-1}+k-\sum_{n=1}^{k}\exp\left(\frac{x^{\frac{4}{\pi}}\left(1-x\right)^{8+n}}{8^{2}}\right)>x!$$

Comment: @Gary Thanks for the edit !

Comment: We can also use : $$f(x)=x!^{\frac{b}{x-1}},b=\left(1+\frac{1}{x+25000}\right)^{x}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici see the derivative of $$\frac{\left(x^{\ln\left(x-e^{-\left(x^{\ln\left(3\right)}\left(1-x^{\ln\left(3\right)}\right)\right)}+1-x^{\ln\left(3\right)}\left(1-x^{\ln\left(3\right)}\right)\right)}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)!}-x!$$ around $x=1$